# Export database data into csv file asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, asynchronous, fs

I'm currently trying to write results of a sql query into a CSV file using `csv-stringify` module for NodeJs.

Here is my code :

```
async exportData() {
        try {
            let request = 'SELECT * FROM PROFACE.dbo.EvenementsMachines WHERE idMachine=215';
            let results = await sql.query(request);

            stringify(results, {
                    header: true
            }, function (err, output) {
                    fs.writeFile(__dirname+'/results.csv', output, function(err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('error : ', err);
                        }
                    });
            })
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

server.app.get("/export", function(req, res) {
    try {
        exportData().then(function(value) {
            res.json("OK");
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    } 
})
```

This piece of code return the following error.

```
CsvError: Invalid argument: got {"header":true} at index 1
    at stringify (C:\Users\c.chaulaic\Documents\Dev\mps-prod\node_modules\csv-stringify\lib\index.js:482:13)
    at DAO.exportData (C:\Users\c.chaulaic\Documents\Dev\mps-prod\server\DAO.js:219:4)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  code: 'CSV_INVALID_ARGUMENT'
```

I guess there is this error because it's asynchrone and the `results` variable is undefined when I use the `stringify()` function. But I don't know how to rewrite my code so it can work fine.

Comment: which npm module are you using ?

Comment: @arjunkori csv-stringify